# Silex - only log to Monolog ErrorLogHandler

Tags: php, apache, silex, monolog

I'd like to log everything using Monolog to webserver (apache's) error log - the same that using error_log() would do.

However, if I set up the logging as follows:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(
    'monolog.logfile' => sys_get_temp_dir().'/app.log'
));

$app['monolog'] = $app->share($app->extend('monolog', function($monolog, $app) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(new ErrorLogHandler(ErrorLogHandler::OPERATING_SYSTEM, Logger::WARNING));
    return $monolog;
}));
```

everything is logged to /tmp/app.log and warning+ to apache error log. The log levels here are not really relevant, I'd like to be able to log to apache log ONLY (mainly for the out-of-the-box support for logrotation).

I guess there are two options:

- Already using the correct path for MonologServiceProvider monolog.logfile (I could define it with 'php_value error_log' in apache vhost config and then use ini_get('error_log') I suppose, though I'd prefer some other solution which doesn't require me to add extra entries to vhost file)
- Somehow overriding the original logging config (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/monolog.html#customization does mention changing the handler but doesn't give an example how to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending your error log handler, how about you [overwrite the default handlers](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L199) using only that one?

```
$app['monolog'] = $app->share($app->extend('monolog', function($monolog, $app) {
    $monolog-> setHandlers([new ErrorLogHandler(ErrorLogHandler::OPERATING_SYSTEM, Logger::WARNING)]);
    return $monolog;
}));
```